# Submeter página após 3 tentativas

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho este formulário simples:

```
    <form class="form-horizontal"  >
<fieldset>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group" align="center">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput"></label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="textinput" name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="Login " class="form-control input-md">
  <span class="help-block"></span>  
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Password input-->
<div class="form-group" align="center" >
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="passwordinput"></label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input id="passwordinput" name="passwordinput" type="password" placeholder="Senha " class="form-control input-md" >
    <span class="help-block"></span>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Button -->
<div class="form-group" align="center" id=addCount>
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="singlebutton"></label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
   <button id="contador" name="singlebutton"  class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>

  </div>
</div>

</fieldset>
</form>
```

Preciso que seja emitido três alertas após submeterem este formulário, na quarta tentativa, direcionar para a página destino. É possível? Tentei via javascript, porem sem sucesso.

Comment: Como assim "na quarta direcionar para a página destino"? Mesmo se os dados estiverem errados direcionar? E o que tentou fazer? Tem como colocar na pergunta o código?

Comment: "Submeter" e "tentar submeter" são coisas distintas.

Comment: É um projeto interno, para conscientização de segurança.

Comment: Mas o que exatamente você está tentando fazer? Se o usuário informar os dados errados aparecer uma mensagem, mas na quarta vez submeter o formulário independente se os dados estão corretos ou não? Isso não parece fazer sentido.

Comment: @Anderson, É como se fosse um Wargame. Pra saber quantas pessoas cairiam em um Phishing.E a quantidade de vezes digitadas pra validar se houve erro de digitação ou não.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Javascript puro sem biblioteca**

Crie uma função javascript que conta os cliques no botão `type="button"` e após terceira tentativa mude o botão para `type="submit"`

```js
 var clicks=0;
 var incrementCount = function(){
     clicks++;
     
     if (clicks==1){
       alert("alerta 1");
     }else if (clicks==2){
       alert("alerta 2");
     }else if (clicks==3){
       alert("alerta 3");
       document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = '<button type="submit"  id="contador" name="singlebutton"  class="btn btn-primary" />Enviar</button>';
     }   
 }
```

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" action="https://pt.stackoverflow.com/">
<fieldset>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group" align="center">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput"></label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="textinput" name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="Login " class="form-control input-md">
  <span class="help-block"></span>  
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Password input-->
<div class="form-group" align="center" >
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="passwordinput"></label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input id="passwordinput" name="passwordinput" type="password" placeholder="Senha " class="form-control input-md" >
    <span class="help-block"></span>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Button -->
<div class="form-group" align="center" id=addCount>
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="singlebutton"></label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
   <div id="demo"><button type="button" id="contador" name="singlebutton"  class="btn btn-primary"  onclick="incrementCount();">Enviar</button>
</div>

  </div>
</div>

</fieldset>
</form>
```

### Sobre o atributo type dos buttons

1. submit: O botão envia os dados do formulário para o servidor.
2. button: O botão não possui comportamento padrão. Ele pode ter scripts do lado do cliente associado com os eventos do elemento, no qual são acionados quando o evento ocorrer.

[`<button>` - Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button)

Comment: :D Agora gostou do "Javascript Puro" né malandro? rss

Comment: @dvd hehehe, pois é, se  tivessem dado resposta com javascript puro, eu talvez desse uma resposta com jquery, o negocio é mostrar alternativas

Answer (score 1):

A pesar de não entender o motivo, você pode manupular o evento `.submit()` usando o `.preventDefault()` para impedir o envio do formulário e em seguida usando o `.unbind("submit").submit()` para ignorar o `.preventDefault()` e submeter o formulário normalmente.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var tentativa = 0;
  $("form").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    tentativa++;
    if (tentativa > 3) {
      $("form").unbind("submit").submit();
    } else {
      alert("Tentativa " + tentativa);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<input type="submit" value="enviar">
</form>
```

Caso esteja usando `jquery` 3.X substitua a `.unbind()` por `.off()`, já que o *unbind* foi descontinuado a partir da versão 3.x

Comment: Queria entender o -1

Comment: Não fui quem deu -1, mas gostaria de comentar: o unbind já foi descontinuado do jQuery. Nem analisei a sua resposta.

Comment: Ah, o unbind foi substituido por .off

Comment: Pois eh, não é melhor usar um código atualizado? A versão 3 já está em 3.2 já tem um tempinho.

Comment: O .off foi adicionado na versão 1.7

Comment: @Erlon, amanhã irei estudar seu código e integrar se possível. Grato pela ajuda.

Comment: @Erlon, seu codigo não funcionou como eu esperava, creio que por falta de conhecimento da minha parte, Do nosso amigo acima, funcionou e também consegui compreender. Grato por sua ajuda.

Comment: @dvd, grato por vosso auxilio tb.